# TeX (not LaTeX) tables, lines, and alignments

Tags: line-spacing, plain-tex

Note: I use TeX and not LaTeX.

So for many years, I have been using this code to create tables with lines:

```
\def\tablerule{\noalign{\vskip1pt\hrule\vskip1pt}}
\vtop to 4truein{
  \halign{
    \strut\vrule#&
    \hskip2pt#\hfil&
    \vrule\hskip2pt\hfil#\hfil\hskip2pt&
    \vrule\hskip2pt\hfil#\hfil\hskip2pt&
    \vrule\hskip2pt\hfil#\hfil\hskip2pt&
    #\vrule\cr
    \tablerule
    & first amper keeps text away from the rule & then i have boxes & of text & last amper keeps text away from the rule & \cr \tablerule
  }
}
```

I don't know how to display the output.  Sorry.

The `\tablerule` horizontal lines have a `\vskip1pt` because, to me, the text with lines in it looks very cramped, and adding the spaces lightens up the text a bit.

However, with the `\vskip1pt`, the vertical lines are not complete.  There are little tiny one-pt white dots where the vertical lines cross the horizontal lines.  Not a huge problem, but one I'd like to fix if I can.

So I'm guessing there should be a way to specify something like "even though I'm using 10 point type, make the height of the line as if it were 14 point type" or something like that.

I tried playing with `\baselineskip`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect inside the `\vbox` or inside the `\halign`.

Comment: To give the output I'm afraid you have to do it the hard way. Compile and take a screenshot. Crop it and upload the image :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard solution is: give bigger `\strut`. For example `\vbox to<xx>{}` creates strut of given height plus depth. The depth is set by `\lower`. More exactly:

```
\def\tablerule{\noalign{\hrule}}
\vtop to 4truein{
  \halign{
    \lower5pt\vbox to16pt{}\vrule#&
    \hskip2pt#\hfil&
    \vrule\hskip2pt\hfil#\hfil\hskip2pt&
    \vrule\hskip2pt\hfil#\hfil\hskip2pt&
    \vrule\hskip2pt\hfil#\hfil\hskip2pt&
    #\vrule\cr
    \tablerule
    & first amper keeps text away from the rule & then i have boxes & of text & last amper keeps text away from the rule & \cr \tablerule
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you chose to use \lower+\vbox for a strut instead of Knuth's use of \vrule (e.g. `\vrule height 11pt depth 5pt width 0pt`)? Of course one should probably make a local def of a strut: `\def\mystrut{\vrule height 11pt depth 5pt width 0pt}` and then use `\mystrut` in the halign template.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate a cell for every vertical rule; with `\omit` you can override the strut in the first cell and add whatever height you need.

```
\def\tablerule{%
  \noalign{\hrule}
}

\vbox{
  \offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt
  \halign{%
    \tabskip=2pt
    \strut\vrule#&
    \hfil#\hfil&
    \vrule#&
    \hfil#\hfil&
    \tabskip=0pt
    \vrule#\cr
    \tablerule
    \omit\vrule height 6pt &&&&\cr
    & hamburgefontstiv&& hamburgefontstiv&\cr
    \omit\vrule height 6pt &&&&\cr
    \tablerule
    \omit\vrule height 6pt &&&&\cr
    & hamburgefontstiv&& hamburgefontstiv&\cr
    \omit\vrule height 6pt &&&&\cr
    \tablerule
  }
}

\bye
```

[image]